# Powershell - New-Object : Index was outside the bounds of the array

Tags: c#, powershell

I have a problem for several days, the execution of the script below causes an execption.

I use multiple C# constructors to help in the entry of a large number of row in an array. 
My problem is probably from my PowerShell syntax, the code works correctly in C#.

I'm new to Powershell, I'm not confident about what I'm doing ...

```
$source = @"
using System.IO;

public class DesktopIni
{
    public const string Shell32 = @"%SystemRoot%\system32\shell32.dll";

    // Ctor without folder, with localizedRes
    public DesktopIni(string root,
        int iconResourceIndex, int localizedResourceIndex,
        string iconResource = Shell32, string localizedResourceName = Shell32)
        : this(root, null, iconResourceIndex, iconResource, localizedResourceIndex, localizedResourceName) { }

    // Ctor without folder, without localizedRes
    public DesktopIni(string root,
        int iconResourceIndex, string iconResource = Shell32)
        : this(root, null, iconResourceIndex, iconResource, 0, null) { }



    // Ctor with folder, with localizedRes
    public DesktopIni(string root, string folderName,
        int iconResourceIndex, int localizedResourceIndex,
        string iconResource = Shell32, string localizedResourceName = Shell32)
        : this(root, folderName, iconResourceIndex, iconResource, localizedResourceIndex, localizedResourceName) { }

    // Ctor with folder, without localizedRes
    public DesktopIni(string root, string folderName,
        int iconResourceIndex, string iconResource = Shell32)
        : this(root, folderName, iconResourceIndex, iconResource, 0, null) { }



    // Full Ctor
    private DesktopIni(string root, string folderName,
        int iconResourceIndex, string iconResource,
        int localizedResourceIndex, string localizedResourceName)
    {
        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(folderName))
            this.FullPath =  Path.Combine(root, folderName);
        else
            this.FullPath =  root;

        this.IconResource = iconResource;
        this.IconResourceIndex = iconResourceIndex;

        this.LocalizedResourceName = localizedResourceName;
        this.LocalizedResourceIndex = localizedResourceIndex;
    }

    public string FullPath;

    public string IconResource;
    public int IconResourceIndex;

    public string LocalizedResourceName;
    public int LocalizedResourceIndex;
}
"@


Add-Type -TypeDefinition $source


$Drive = $env:HOMEDRIVE + '\'
$Folders = @()

$Folders += New-Object DesktopIni "C:\Demo1", 160
$Folders += New-Object DesktopIni $Drive, "Demo2", 160
$Folders += New-Object DesktopIni "C:\Demo3", 160, -21813
$Folders += New-Object DesktopIni $Drive, "Demo4", 160, -21813

$Folders | Format-Table
```

Exception :

```
New-Object : Index was outside the bounds of the array.
Au caractère C:\Users\Jeremy\Desktop\2 - Programs\test.ps1:69 : 13
+ $Folders += New-Object DesktopIni $Drive, "Demo2", 160
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-Object], IndexOutOfRangeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IndexOutOfRangeException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Com 
   mands.NewObjectCommand
```

And the same exception for the other 2 rows.

Can you tell me the correct syntax, thank you.

Comment: This is not an issue with the array assignment. It is a problem with the parameters used in New-Object. Executed the New-Object code outside the array assignment and you will see the same issue. You need to see the way constructors are written or the values you are passing.

Answer (score 2):

You appear to have found a bug with New-Object, and how it behaves when constructors with default parameter values are defined.  This error can be reproduced with a very simple test class:

```
Add-Type -TypeDefinition @'
public class TestClass
{
    public TestClass(int anInt, string aString = "") { }
    public TestClass(int anInt) { }
}
'@

New-Object TestClass 1
```

I'd suggest reporting the bug over on the Connect site:  http://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell